# PageView.Builder in Flutter The getter 'length' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: length

Tags: flutter, viewbuilder

*when use response from API then show error*
**The getter 'length' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: length**
**here is my API code**

```
var url =
      "https://domain.php";
  var res;
  var splashs;
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    fetchData();
  }

  fetchData() async {
    res = await http.get(url);
    splashs = jsonDecode(res.body);
    setState(() {});
  }
```

*while use List then code working properly*

```
 List<Map<String, String>> splashs = [
    {
      "header": "Flatros",
      "text": "Welcome to Flatros, Let’s shop!",
      "image_name": "assets/images/splash_1.png"
    },
    {
      "header": "Shopping",
      "text":
          "We help people conect with store \naround United State of America",
      "image_name": "assets/images/splash_2.png"
    },
    {
      "header": "Multi Category",
      "text": "FInal Screen",
      "image_name": "assets/images/splash_3.png"
    },
  ];
```

Comment: Try to call with `FutureBuilder` or you can show loader until data gets

Comment: You can post your UI code so we can help with suggestions

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede i try also ListView.Builder and FutureBuilder but same problem

Comment: @YasirMehmood please add your code

Comment: @YasirMehmood what you are getting here `res.body`

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026103/list-generate-the-getter-length-was-called-on-null-receiver-null-tried-calli

Comment: @ShubhamNarkhede res.body also print on link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66026103/list-generate-the-getter-length-was-called-on-null-receiver-null-tried-calli

Comment: @YasirMehmood please check my answer and let me know what you will get

Answer (score 0):

May be you need to convert your data into `List` or `Array`

```
  List splashs = new List();
  
  fetchData() async {
    res = await http.get(url);
    final data = jsonDecode(res.body);
    for (var i in data) {
      splashs.add(i);   // Create a list and add data one by one
    }
    setState(() {});
  }
```